# Add an additional arrow in circular smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, smartdiagram

I want to add another arrow betweem module1 and module3 of my circular smartdiagram, but can't figure out how to do it.

My diagram looks like this:

[image: current diagram]

And should contain a arrow like this:

[image: expected diagram]

Below is a MWE of my current diagram

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{
        circular final arrow disabled=true, 
    }
    \smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{
        A, B, C, D
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the additions library of `smartdiagram`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \smartdiagramset{
        circular final arrow disabled=true, 
        additions={
            additional arrow color=black,
            additional arrow tip=stealth,
            additional arrow line width=2pt,
        }
    }
    \smartdiagramadd[circular diagram:clockwise]{
        A, B, C, D
    }{}
    \smartdiagramconnect{->}{module3/module1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: thank you. I tried the additions library, but didn't get it to work. My mistake was actually using `\smartdiagram` instead of `\smartdiagramadd`

Comment: using `{->, shorten >=8pt, shorten <=8pt}` as the arrow style also offsets it approximately like the default arrows

Comment: Is it possible to use arow tips on both ends, like *if and only if* arrow?

Comment: You mean like this? `\smartdiagramconnect{<->}{module3/module1}`

Comment: @Benjamin, I'd like on curved arrows. The vertical I'll delete. I want equilateral triangle format with circular arrows.

Comment: By the way. You probably should have asked a new question. Because your question does not have anything to do with the original question. To answer your question: add `arrow style=<->,` inside `\smartdiagramset{•}`.