# Add additional arrow to smartdiagram constellation

Tags: arrows, smartdiagram

I need to add an arrow between two satellites in a smartdiagram constellation.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  set color list={orange!60, green!50!lime!60,magenta!60,blue!50!cyan},
  uniform connection color=true,
  planet text width=2.5cm,
  planet font=\normalfont,
  distance planet-satellite=4.5cm,
  satellite text width=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
} 
\smartdiagramadd[constellation diagram]{Text Comprehension,
  Navigation, Dialogue, Memory Offloading}{
  }
\end{document}
```

Which gives me:
[image]

What I need is an arrow between the two left-hand nodes, something like this:
[image]

I've tried using:

```
\smartdiagramconnect{{<->}}{module2/module1}
```

and

```
\smartdiagramconnect{{<->}}{satellite2/satellite1}
```

But in both cases there is an error: No shape named ...

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283407/add-an-additional-arrow-in-circular-smartdiagram

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `smartdiagram` names the satellites `satellite2`, `satellite3` etc. rather than starting from `satellite1`, as one might have expected.

Also, the additions won't work correctly with the `standalone` class.

Correcting these things, the code compiles as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
\begin{document}

\smartdiagramset{
  set color list={orange!60, green!50!lime!60,magenta!60,blue!50!cyan},
  uniform connection color=true,
  planet text width=2.5cm,
  planet font=\normalfont,
  distance planet-satellite=4.5cm,
  satellite text width=2.5cm,
  /tikz/connection planet satellite/.append style={<-}
}
\smartdiagramadd[constellation diagram]{%
  Text Comprehension,
  Navigation,
  Dialogue,
  Memory Offloading%
}{}
\smartdiagramconnect{<->}{satellite2/satellite3}
\end{document}
```

[image: output from corrected code, connecting first two satellites]